# Is it needed a relay snubber in an ammeter?

Tags: relay, current-measurement, snubber

I'm designing a picoammeter for an academic project, with different current ranges. To switch between current ranges I should use some relay, driven by a micro. This kind of ammeter should be able to measure current in a bidirectional fashion, and should measure only resistive load, but i would consider it slightly inductive due to wiring.
I was wondering though if it would be necessary a snubber or something else in this portion of the circuit.
[image]

What do you think? is it necessary? if yes, what kind of snubber should i use to avoid any parasitic artifact in the measurement?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. It is the the coil of the relay that is inductive which requires a flyback diode or snubber. Not the primary contacts. Everything has a non-zero inductance, but you aren't going to put a snubber across everything unless it's large enough to cause damage. For pA measurements, practically anything extra is going to cause inaccuracies.

Comment: Your \$ I_{SENSE} \$ seems to be missing a connection to something. It's also labeled as 1u. If that's \$ 1 \ \mu \Omega; \$ and you're measuring pA the shunt voltage will be \$ 10^{-18} \ \text V \$. Can you clarify in your question?

Comment: @Transistor I used the ISENSE resistor to measure the current that is flowing in that part of the circuit in SPICE. It's only for simulation purposes. When i modified my design adding R88, i forgot to remove it :)

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the answer :) i was worried indeed to put something like a snubber in this "precision" circuit that could cause inaccuracies

Comment: OK, so you'll remove the 1u and then what? You've got an inverting op-amp with a DC blocking capacitor in the feedback and nowhere for the bias current to go.

Comment: R88 is used to limit the current for the protection diodes of the opamp. The capacitor is used to form a low pass filter with one of the 4 resitors, so DC current can actually flow. The feedback is not only formed by the capacitor, but also by one of the 4 selectable resistor.

Comment: Your most sensitive range is using a very large value resistor making this design extremely difficult. Learn and follow the high-impedance guidelines in the datasheet. You will also need to shield the circuit from electrostatic fields. Having a relay in the path will make this nearly impossible to get to work reliably with the 1G resistor.

Comment: @Mattman944 How are such low currents normally measured?

Comment: @DKNguyen - Not sure how to measure femto amps. I designed a picoamp sensor with a 300M resistor once, and that was challenging enough. The traces to the large value resistor should be short, the relays will add trace length and create more opportunities for leakage currents.

Comment: @Mattman944 So you still use big resistors, albeit really carefully, and not some radically different approach? That's all I was really after.

Comment: @DKNguyen - If there is another method, I am not aware of it. If the opamp offset voltage and input current is low enough, you can use a smaller resistor value and add a second voltage amplification stage.